# Dynamic programming : the case when a subproblem graph is not an acyclic graph?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

In dynamic programming, subproblem graphs are considered as directed acyclic graphs (dag) but how to solve when a subproblem graph contains a cycle? For example solution of *subproblem(a)* depends on the solutions of *subproblem(b)* and *subproblem(c)*, again solution of *subproblem(b)* depends on the solution of subproblem(a)...

Comment: I think then it is not applicable to use dynamic programming...or do you have an example?

Answer (score 2):

In some cases (precisely when values of the function depend linearly on each other) you can reduce your problem to solving a system of linear equations. For example, if you know that

```
sub(a) = sub(b) + sub(c)
sub(b) = sub(c) * 2 + 5
sub(c) = sub(a) - 1
```

then you can make a linear system which looks like a matrix. In this case it will be

```
       a   b   c    value
eq.1   1  -1  -1      0
eq.2   0   1  -2      5
eq.3  -1   0   1     -1
```

So, you have a matrix A and a vector **c**, and you want to find such **x** that A**x** = **c**. Vector **x** will contain values of your variables in order. This can be done with standard linear algebra algorithms, presumably Gaussian transform.